# Mejorar la performance cuando hay transacciones largas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, transacciones

Tengo una transaccion T1 que actualiza varios registros de la BD (puede tardar horas) y al mismo tiempo otras transacciones Tj que intentan leer datos de la misma tabla.

Qué enfoque es el recomendado para tratar este caso, se puede hacer algo seteando el nivel de isolación de las transacciones?

Es posible que las transacciones Tj se sirvan con los datos que hayan sido commiteados antes de que comenzara la transacción T1?

Me gustaría evitar lecturas sucias de los cambios de T1.

Comment: Las columnas que consultas cuando haces la transacción, están indexadas? Supongo que la actualización de datos se tarda por la selección de los datos que deben de ser actualizados y no por la actualización como tal. Si ese es el caso, deberías probar indexar las columnas que usas para la selección.

Comment: Las columnas están indexadas. El problema me parece que se reduce a que la Transacción que actualiza tiene un lockeo exclusivo de los registros hasta que se complete o aborte. Esto no permite que otras transacciones pueda obtener un lockeo compartido para la lectura.

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar más información del problema por favor? Para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Lo que se me ocurre es tener una réplica de sólo lectura, y que las transacciones Tj que van a leer de la tabla, lean de la réplica, mientras que T1 actualiza la tabla y cuando termine actualice las réplicas. No sé si sea el approach correcto, quizá como dices, modificando un poco los locks se pueda lograr sin tener réplicas.

Comment: Lamento no poder brindar mucha información. La aplicación está en etapa de diseño. Pero me voy a encontrar con este caso, donde tengo una transacción muy larga que lockea una tabla ( o varios registros de la misma), y las transsacciones que quieran leer van a quedar suspendidas por un buen rato.
Lo de la tabla de réplica me gustó. Creo que esa podría ser una solución viable.

Comment: Así es, de cualquier forma, si llegas a encontrar una mejor respuesta, compártela por favor, es una muy interesante pregunta. Creo que todos nos beneficiaríamos y nos gustaría conocer otras formas de optimizar la base de datos